# how to integrate bootstrap4 based menu into wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, bootstrap-4

I have my customize menu based on bootstrap4 which is working well on mobile and desktop. In my website, i am using twenty-seventeen themes. i want to replace default menu with my customize menu. i read lot of articles but nothing find suitable.

The issues is i have some user defined classes which is i am using with my dropdown  menu and others js file as well. i can enqueue them into functions.php. and i'll upload wp-bootsrap-walker into my theme as well. but in the portion inside nav , where i need to add php code in place of my code. it'll change all the styles which is defined for user defined classes. Thanks , expecting a brief solutions.

Comment: can you post your html and wp-bootsrap-walker code?

Comment: you can download bootstrap-navwaker from this link https://github.com/mebishalnapit/bootstrap-navwalker                                               and for sample menu you can use this html.   jsfiddle.net/my3oje9t/1

Answer (score 0):

you must add the navwalker to your theme
Just read the below og google "navwalker and wordpress"

https://napitwptech.com/tutorial/wordpress-development/integrate-bootstrap-navwalker-wordpress-theme/

Comment: hello elisa, according to this article, i download their navwalker file and upload it inside my theme folder. sorry could you please elaborate your suggestion? thanks

Comment: you need include nav walker in functions.php file like `require get_template_directory() . '/inc/wp_bootstrap_navwalker.php';`

Comment: my name is Elias, you must create headep.php, footer.php and in the header.php have something like

Comment: <?php
            wp_nav_menu(array(
              'theme_location'  => 'primary',
              'depth'           => 2,
              'container'       => false,
              'menu_class'      => 'nav nav-pills pull-right',
              'fallback'        => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
              'walker'          => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker()
            ));
          ?>

Comment: yes I agree you must include in functions php , another solution require_once('wp_bootstrap_navwalker.php');

Comment: i register the navwalker in my functions.php. but the problem is my nav bar has some customize css and i am calling user defined classes. that's why i can't replace the code with php... i read lot of articles.. all did the same but no one explain what to do if you have customized code.